# Php RecursiveIteratorIterator through tarball keeping original file order

Tags: php, iterator, tar

In a tarball files are sorted by the time when they're pushed in. In the following example they are not sorted alphabetically, but in push-order.

```bash
# tar tvf file.tgz
-rw-r--r-- 0/0       962 2023-01-17 13:40:17 6fe3b8b5-a4dc-4976-bea9-227434c11cda
-rw-r--r-- 0/0       962 2023-01-17 13:40:17 febe009e-8ce0-4027-abda-e27f5f949dde
-rw-r--r-- 0/0       962 2023-01-17 13:40:17 4fea07a6-a90c-4cb4-9969-4cac08422ccf
-rw-r--r-- 0/0       962 2023-01-17 13:40:17 01610297-c577-4e6c-9ce9-7825a40e6d0c
-rw-r--r-- 0/0       962 2023-01-17 13:40:26 01b498ca-3d87-426b-b01d-d4e75921cb00
-rw-r--r-- 0/0       962 2023-01-17 13:40:26 45821111-f69d-4331-87d8-f3afd9918c91
```

Surprisingly when reading the above tarball with PHP 8.1 `RecursiveIteratorIterator` they are iterated alphabetically.

```php
$p = new PharData($path);
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($p) as $file) {
    echo $file . "\n";
}
```

The above code results in the output below:

```bash
phar:///path/to/file/01610297-c577-4e6c-9ce9-7825a40e6d0c
phar:///path/to/file/01b498ca-3d87-426b-b01d-d4e75921cb00
phar:///path/to/file/45821111-f69d-4331-87d8-f3afd9918c91
phar:///path/to/file/4fea07a6-a90c-4cb4-9969-4cac08422ccf
phar:///path/to/file/6fe3b8b5-a4dc-4976-bea9-227434c11cda
phar:///path/to/file/febe009e-8ce0-4027-abda-e27f5f949dde
```

Is there a way in PHP to iterate over tarball content in the original order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Alex Howansky answer I found a working solution based on [exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), that basically take advantage of tar sorted listing:

```php
$sortedFileList = [];
exec("tar tf $path", $sortedFileList);
$sortedFileList = array_flip($sortedFileList);

$p = new PharData($path);
$files = iterator_to_array($p);
usort($files,
    fn(a, $b) => $sortedFileList[$a->getFilename()] <=> $sortedFileList[$b->getFilename()]
);

foreach ($files as $file) {
    printf("%s %s\n", $file->getPathname(), $file->getMTime());
}
```

I'm not a big fan of using exec, but the only alternative to achieve my goal would be to add some external library to the project, and since this work should be done by plain [PharData](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.phardata.php) iterator I hope that in a future it will permit to iterate tarball files in raw order.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is caused by `PharData` class, not `RecursiveIteratorIterator`. You can force your own sort by converting to an array first, then using `usort()` on whatever field you want:

```
$p = new PharData(...);
$files = iterator_to_array($p);
usort($files, fn($a, $b) => $a->getMTime() <=> $b->getMTime());
foreach ($files as $file) {
    printf("%s %s\n", $file->getPathname(), $file->getMTime());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but my tarball can be potentially very big, leading to a memory leak if converted to an array. I'm digging into PharData [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.phardata.php) to see if there is a way to iterate the tarball in the correct order, but it is really incomplete.

Comment: _"leading to a memory leak if converted to an array"_ A leak? Not sure you how you come to that conclusion. TAR files have an index. You'll be converting that index to an array -- not the actual files in the TAR.

Comment: You're right, since it'only some byte for file also with 500K of them we are speaking about some Mb of data. I tried your solution and it works quite fine, the problem is that for the initial 4 files in my example, that shares the same mtime, the sorted order is not the same, they are printed in alphabetical order, grouped by mtime.  

If there is no way to access them in in the original order this workarond may be fine.

Comment: [splitbrain/php-archive](https://github.com/splitbrain/php-archive) might work better for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggested library, but I prefer to not fill my projects with a lot of external libraries, in order to be light and fast during sw upgrade. I ended up with a working solution, based on your response. I will share it soon.